# How do I run a callback when all objects have stopped moving?

Tags: physics, bullet-physics, callbacks

I'm using Bullet and want to take some action once all objects in a dynamic world have reached 0 velocity (or at least a value that's very close).

I was trying to iterate over all of them all the time and when a counter equals `getNumCollisionObjects()` then do that action. But it's a complex procedure and I'm beginning to think it's unnecessary.

Is there a better way, perhaps by comparing two frames or a Bullet built-in?

Comment: Are there not callbacks for objects coming to rest and awakening?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [isActive()](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionObject.html#a750500d282af3411ac0c1266b4951e77) on each btCollisionObject. It just returns a boolean, so it's easy to work with.

Alternatively, you can call [getActivationState()](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionObject.html#aae03a9420baefc03be2b9288ad669b58) which returns an int representing one of [these values](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Activation_States), but you shouldn't need to.

To optimize, if you really need to, I'd just add all collision objects to a list. Loop through this list every frame, removing each inactive object you come across until you find a single active one, then break out of the loop. Or just loop through all objects every frame. Premature optimization is usually not worth it.